# PHP global keyword workaround

Tags: php, global-variables

Isn't there another way of using global variables in a Java stlye manner in PHP without the use of the `global` keyword?

The below example is something very common and simple. I would do it with the `define` keyword, but as you can see, the varibales are dependent from each other, and I believe you can't achieve that with `define`.

In the below example I am getting an error, of course.

Really looking forward a solution for this. It just seems to me that having to write a `global` definition for which funciton I want to use a global variable seems such an ineffective solution that should be a better one.

```
$BASE_URL = "mysite.com";
$PRODUCTS_URL = $BASE_URL . "/products";
$ABOUT_URL = $BASE_URL . "/about";

function foo() {
    echo $BASE_URL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would do it with the define keyword, but as you can see, the varibales are dependent from each other, and I believe you can't achieve that with define.

Not quite true, this will work just fine - and it's the way I would probably approach this:

```
define('BASE_URL', "mysite.com");
define('PRODUCTS_URL', BASE_URL . "/products");
define('ABOUT_URL', BASE_URL . "/about");
```

Just be careful about eating up constant namespace, you might want to write a function instead, maybe something like this (could use tweaking, just an example):

```
function get_url($item = NULL, $include_base = TRUE)
{
    $urls = array(
        'base'  =>  'mysite.com',
        'products'  =>  '/products',
        'about' =>  '/about',
    );
    $output = $include_base ? $urls['base'] : '';
    if (isset($urls[$item])) $output .= $urls[$item];
    return $output;
}
```

Then call it like `echo get_url('products');`. As long as this is defined when `foo()` is called, it will work. I would always strive to avoid `global` or `$GLOBALS`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $GLOBALS superglobal as follows...

```
function foo() {
    echo $GLOBALS['BASE_URL'];
}
```

However - see Kolink's comment below. From [PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0) the $GLOBALS superglobal is only initialised on first use, so there's a marginal performance advantage in not using it and sticking with the [global](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword.

For the kind of thing you're doing, you could simply define a single global array, e.g.

```
 $CONF['BASE_URL']='foo';
```

Then you just need use `global $CONF` in any function that needs it, or better yet, wrap it into some kind of configuration class.

Comment: Note that the `$GLOBALS` array is added just-in-time in PHP 5.4. In this case, it would be inefficient to call it just to avoid specifying `global $myvar`.

Comment: Interesting - if anyone needs a reference for that, see the changelog for 5.4.0 here http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0

Answer (score 0):

You could even use `$_SESSION` but not a very elegant solution.
Why is it so hard for you to type `global` ? It is not big rush.

`define()` is good as well.